# absolute positioning not aligning properly

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-position, absolute

The following code...

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $thumbnail_url ?>')" <?php post_class('container-fluid'); ?> >

<div class="container-fluid text-cell">
   <div class="col-md-12 textr">
     <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php  the_title(); ?></a></h2>
     <?php the_category(', '); ?>
   </div>   
</div>

</article><!-- /#post -->
```

... Creates the posts for my Wordpress theme. It makes a row (100% width) with title, category, and background-image. Each post is stacked on top of each other.

I want the title and category to stay at the bottom of the article ( I put a class of 'textr' on the div so they are grouped together.

However that div now sits on top of the article it should be in, not inside and at the bottom

css

```
article {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  background-position: left center;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.text-cell {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.textr{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `position: relative;` from `.text-cell` to `article`

or

You can also modify `.text-cell` to this:

```
.text-cell {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: I managed to fix it! Although your methods do not work (I can't position the article absolute cause then it wouldn't stack) and the changes to text-cell doesn't fix the issue. Adding position:relative to article did however